# Facebook Object Debugger - Could not resolve the hostname into a valid IP address

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, dns, web-scraping, scrape

There is a problem with how Facebook scrapes my page for meta data.

When I use the Facebook object debugger I get the following error:
[image]

I am quite sure this has something to do with how my DNS records are defined. It seems the scraper can't even reach my site. As the error states, it can't turn the host name to a valid IP.

When I press the link down the page "See exactly what out scra...", I get "Document returned no data".

I am trying to figure it for about a month now and getting VERY VERY frustrated.
Can someone shed some light on the subject ?

Comment: http://collector.co.il

Comment: to be more specific: http://collector.co.il/Album/Info/226

Comment: Worked for me when I clicked Fetch new scrape information

Comment: Did you tried the second link ?

Comment: Yes that is the one I tried. If it doesn't work for you I would suggest that you file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: How did this get resolved?

Comment: The guy at my hosting company pulled some leavers and the problem wen't away. Probably a DNS thing, which I know nothing about.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, mind giving us just a bit more info about what your hosting company changed to make this work?

Comment: The most detailed answer I got was that they recreated the DNS records regarding my site.

Comment: I was facing the same issue. Then I clicked "fetch new scrape information" within the facebook linter and problem fixed

Answer (score 6):

After digging for 3 days came to the conclusion that name servers were configured incorrectly.

I am using Bigrock for the domain and GoDaddy for hosting, by mistake, I configured actual hosting provider hostname in "Name Server 3" and "Name Server 4". But Facebook looks for the content in first server "bigrocks-1.com"(wrong server) server but does not find any hosting and throughs 'Could not resolve the hostname into a valid IP address'.

So do remember to put hosting provider address on the first name server

Hope it may help you :)

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It was problem with nameservers.

Answer (score 0):

ok i had the exact same problem and solution was in the dns ... facebook is not able to fetch the data cause of wrong server name ... you need to get in touch with the hosting service provider where your website is hosted or from where you brought your domain name and ask for the right nanme s

Answer (score 0):

For me, clearing the cache from my WordPress Plugin (WpRocket) and Cloudflare solved the issue.