# Unable to Access Website in Google Cloud Storage After Migrating

Tags: web, google-cloud-platform, get

Ok, I'm in the process of migrating my static website www.jvpcs.org from godaddy to Google Cloud Storage. But after completing all the steps. I'm still not able to access my site through the browser. I use this tutorial from Google Cloud https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website. One of the steps is to create a CNAME record with your hosting provider.

```
www.example.com       CNAME    c.storage.googleapis.com
```

then create bucket and verify website ownership... "done"
finally, upload your content and set permission to allUsers (make it public) done!
it has been 24h since I created the record. It should have been propagated through DNS servers. But the site is not working. I tried testing domain resolution by pinging my site which is www.jvpcs.org and I'm getting error. which means is not pointing to any ip address

```
ping jvpcs.org
Ping request could not find host jvpcs.org. Please check the name and try again.
```

next I went to google cloud troubleshooting page. they ask you to test your project by going in to cloud console and list the content of your bucket.. but that's about it

```
gelouis25@cloudshell:~ (leafy-catbird-277515)$ gsutil ls -R gs://www.jvpcs.org
gs://www.jvpcs.org/jvpcs.org/:
gs://www.jvpcs.org/jvpcs.org/JLanScan.sublime-workspace
gs://www.jvpcs.org/jvpcs.org/custom.css
gs://www.jvpcs.org/jvpcs.org/index.html
```

any help appreciated.

Comment: It looks like something goes wrong with DNS configuration. You can check your CNAME record with online tools like [mxtoolbox](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=cname%3ajvpcs.org&run=toolpage). Please update your question with configuration of DNS zone.

Comment: ok... now  it is working. I needed to add an A record. But I had to point to ip address, which is the ip address of godaddy. how do I make it point to google cloud server which is where my page resides. the tutorial say to include a cname to c.storage.googleapis.com but A record points to different place. how exactly this suppose to work

Comment: correction on the comment above.. it is not working as it should it is pointing to old ip address server. how can I make it point to google cloud server. I have added the c.storage.googleapis.com cname record

Comment: new error after I deleted the folder on local server at godaddy "Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@jvpcs.pctechtips.org to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error."

Comment: You have to add only `CNAME` record like `www.jvpcs.org       CNAME c.storage.googleapis.com`, no other records required for now (better to remove old records).  Please update your question with DNS zone configuration to make me able to check it. You have only one `CNAME` record `www.jvpcs.org CNAME jvpcs.org` at the moment as I can see.

Comment: I just talk to godaddy tech support, they say I needed to add A record, I had deleted the record when I added CNAME. but still wasn't working fater 24 hrs..

Comment: I had deleted the A record previously, gave it 24 hrs didn't work. a CNAME record is meant to forward domain resolution to another domain server in this c.storage.googleapis.com

Comment: I doubt that GoDaddy support is able help you to configure DNS for hosting of static web site at GCP. You need to have A record if you want to host your site at GoDaddy or do something else. If you want to switch to GCP the only record you need is CNAME accordingly to the documentation.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61676499). It was solved by proper configuration of DNS zone.