# Google Cloud static website is not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have created static website on google Cloud, when I setup everything... for first time it worked fine.. but from second day its stopped working, and I'm not able to find the solution for the same.

my website is keydial.in

please, help me to get out from this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I see your CNAME record in Cloud DNS configuration isn't set, have a look:

```
wbogacz@cloudshell:~ (wojtek)$ dig CNAME keydial.in

; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P4-5.1+deb10u1-Debian <<>> CNAME keydial.in
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 35276
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;keydial.in.                    IN      CNAME

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
keydial.in.             299     IN      SOA     ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com. cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com. 1 21600 3600 259200 300

;; Query time: 20 msec
;; SERVER: 169.254.169.254#53(169.254.169.254)
;; WHEN: Fri Aug 21 09:38:15 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 132
```

Please change it to `keydial.in` and wait until the changes propagate across the Internet (up to 24 hours).

[Similar case was discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61680871/12257250) - it was also a matter of CNAME record.